# How to determine whether this situation belongs to data leakage or not

Tags: data-science, data-labelling

Suppose that I use three features (x1, x2, x3) to predict the value of y. After hyperparameters tuning, the r2 score on train/valid/test set is 0.92, 0.54, 0.55 respectively, it's not so good.*(It is called "original" below)*

There are some relationships between x1 and y, so I change the prediction target from y to y/x1, the situation becomes using x1, x2, x3 to predict y/x1, the r2 score on train/valid/test set becomes 0.91, 0.72, 0.73, the performance of model is *improved than origin*, but **is this data leakage?**

Similarly, if use x1, x2, x3 to predict y/x2, the r2 score on train/valid/test set is 0.90, 0.64, 0.64 *(slightly increase than original)*; if use x1, x2, x3 to predict y/x3, the r2 score on train/valid/test set is 0.85, 0.45, 0.56 *(almost same as original)*. **If introduce feature into target belongs to data leakage, why doesn't the introduction of different features into target lead to a significant improvment in r2 score?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you explain your rationale for changing the target from y to y/x1?